# Ninject WCF extension adding an error handler

Tags: wcf, ninject, ierrorhandler

I am trying to use Ninject.Extensions.Wcf for DI on my web service but want to also inject a custom IErrorHandler.

As far as I know this should be done in the ApplyDispatchBehavior method of the custom IServiceBehavior, but I don't see any way to override Ninject's service behavior.

Comment: Why don't you add this behavior using a decorator as shown in [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95)?

Comment: I wanted to combine the DI and error handler in one behavior. That approach would result in two behaviors, which I don't even know is allowed (?). Anyway, I ended up just using the basic Ninject package and implementing the behavior and associated factories from scratch, not very complicated at all it turned out.